# Андроид, почему не может установить фрагмент из переменной?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Привет, у меня проблема, мой телефон показывает черный экран, когда я пытаюсь вставить объект своего класса в FragmentTransaction

```
LoginFragment lf = new LoginFragment();
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.add(R.id.loginContainer, lf).commit();
```

Но если я добавляю экземпляр класса, то все работает отлично

```
fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fTrans.add(R.id.loginContainer,
    new LoginFragment()).commit();
```

Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь это сделать на своем LG, на котором стоит 4.0.3, а на 4.2.2 и выше все нормально работает. Подскажите, из-за чего вылазит такой баг.

Весь код onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_loginreg);
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
@Override
public void uncaughtException(Thread paramThread,
Throwable paramThrowable) {
final StringWriter errors = new StringWriter();
paramThrowable.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(errors));
Log.e("Alert", errors.toString());
new Thread(new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
Log.d("tst",
new Connector().addException(errors.toString()));
}
}).start();

}
});
blockSteps = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.blockSteps);
stepsText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stepsText);
imgStep1 = (View) findViewById(R.id.imgStep1);
imgStep2 = (View) findViewById(R.id.imgStep2);
imageLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

fManager = new FragmentStackManager(); //my own class
fManager.addFragment(new StackFragment(0)); // stack 1
fManager.addFragment(new StackFragment(1)); // stack 2

fManager.getStack(0).addFragment(new LoginFragment(0)); //add fragment for 1 (start) stack

fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

//fManager.getStartFragment().getCurFragment() = LoginFragment not null
fTrans.add(R.id.loginContainer,
fManager.getStartFragment().getCurFragment()).commit(); // set

Log.d("oncreate", "create"); // login
fragment = fManager.getStartFragment().getCurFragment();

face = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),
"roboto_regular.ttf");
stepsText.setTypeface(face);
}
```

Comment: Приведенный Вами код эквивалентен, проблема где-то в другом месте. Приведите весь код 1-го варианта.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja привел чуть выше

Comment: Если можно, еще FragmentStackManager, пожалуста. Но в нем я уже вижу проблему. В Андроид нельзя сохранять ссылки на фрагменты, потому что система его может без уведомления уничтожить и создать снова, при повороте экрана, нехватке памяти или еще чего. В результате фрагмент на экране уже не будет из вашего стека. Вместо этого пользуйтесь "мягкими" ссылками  
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html  
и всегда проверяйте если она еще "жива".